# Adding modulo 128-bit numbers

Tags: arrays, math, addition, subtraction

I have some 2 numbers of 128 bits. Let it be the same number:

```
A=282434364544378924672110924168367615433
B=282434364544378924672110924168367615433
```

It is necessary to add them modulo numbers

```
340282366920938463460374607431768211337
```

To represent 128-bit numbers, I use two 64-bit arrays

```
low_A = A.aa[0];
low_B = B.aa[0];
low_M = M.aa[0];
high_A = A.aa[1];
high_B = B.aa[1];
high_M = M.aa[1];
```

Thus, selecting the lower and upper parts (we can roughly say that in this way the numbers will be presented to the 64th number system).
The problem is that when adding the numbers A and B, an overflow occurs physically. The transfer is performed to a non-existent bit, although the binary representation remains true. If there was a transfer, we certainly already know that the given number is greater than the modulus.
How then do we explain to the machine what the result should be

```
A+B-M

if (high_A <= ULLONG_MAX - high_B) flag_h = 0; else flag_h = 1;
if (flag_h) {
    int car = 0;
    high_A = high_A - high_M;
    high_B = high_B - high_M;
    high_C = high_A + high_B + high_M;
    if (low_C <= low_M)
    {
        low_C = low_M - low_C;
        low_C = ULLONG_MAX - low_C + 1;
        car = 1;
    }
    else { low_C = low_C - low_M; }
    high_C -= car;
}
```

I tried to do this in the above manner, but still the program finds it wrong.
I explain what I wanted to do. I tried to make a mathematical formula `(A-M) + (B-M) + M = (A + B-M)`. I'm trying to subtract from the senior and junior level.
Let's show on the numbers

```
_ 51
  38
 1) 8-1 = 7, 7 more will have to be subtracted
 2) We simulate a loan at the senior level
 3) 10-7 = 9 + 1 - 7 = 3
 4) Set loan flag in the unit
 5) 5 - 3 - flag = 1
 6) 13
```

Comment: Hi, Ayrat, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you've found a solution to your own problem, you're welcome to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer), but please post your answer *as an answer*, not as part of your question. Also, please tag your question with the language you're using; I assume it's either C or C++, but it would be nice to know which.

Comment: Please explain how to leave a comment in the form of a code! Does not work!

Comment: There should be a blue "Answer Your Question" button at the bottom of the page (above the footer). Click that, and then type your answer into the edit box that appears.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to the problem, began to subtract from the higher order, here is the code

```
if (flag_h) 
{
    int car = 0;
    unsigned __int64 temp1,temp2;
    if (high_C < high_M)
    {
        temp1 = high_M - high_C;
        high_C = ULLONG_MAX - temp1 + 1;
    }
    else { high_C = high_C - high_M; }
    if (low_C < low_M) {
        temp2 = low_M - low_C;
        low_C = ULLONG_MAX - temp2 + 1;
        high_C--;
    }
    else { low_C = low_C - low_M; }
}
```